# Testing attribute text to match part of href link in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm testing all the links on a page but I only want a partial match.

I can test the full href like this

```js
cy.visit('/');
cy.get('.class').find('a').should("have.attr", "href", "/123/456");
```

but I want to test the string partially, for example `/456`. I tried `.contains()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `include`,

```js
cy.get('.class').find('a')
  .should('have.attr', 'href')
  .and('include', '/456');
```

or you can switch the subject

```js
cy.get('.class').find('a')
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .should('contain', '/456');
```

or a longer version using jquery

```js
cy.get('.class').find('a')
  .should('have.attr', 'href')
  .then(href => {
    expect(href.endsWith('/456')).to.be.true;
  });
```